# Is there any way to compare two spectograms?

Tags: algorithm, comparison, sound-recognition

I am trying to compare two spectrograms of two different spoken words. Is there any way to compare these to say these two spectrograms are from different words.

Hello (word i spoken)
[image: HELLO]

[image: Play]

Play (word i spoken)

Comment: Have you thought of maybe using speech recognition software? (Sorry, but this question is far too broad. I'm voting to close.)

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare the spectrograms? Wouldn't it be easier to compare the WAV representation of the sound? However, this is not a simple matter of looking for exact matches. You have to make allowances for background noise and, if you want to recognize the same word spoken by two different people, it gets much more interesting (difficult). Without a more specific question, this is way too broad for Stackoverflow.